# Nginx server_name & listen matches specified patterns

Tags: nginx

In this example the domain has been replaced with domain.com

Our main issue:
When i type https://domain.com i don't get redirected to https://www.domain.com, we currently don't have a rule for this what would be the best way to solve this?

According to our nginx configuration we have not specified 443 for https://domain.com but still its accessible, why is that?

We have valid ssl certificates for both domain.com and www.domain.com.
We do not have a wildcard certificate *.domain.com.

Our Configuration:

```
#All non-matching patterns
server
{
  listen 80;

  #enabling this will cause things to break.
  #2015/12/18 09:21:54 [error] 32165#0: *1661 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: *censored*, server: 0.0.0.0:443
  #listen 443 ssl;

  #Horrible looking match all pattern.
  server_name _ "" domain.com *.domain.com;

  return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

#Main site ssl enforced
server
{
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.domain.com ios.domain.com android.domain.com;

  ...
}

#Staging / Test site
server
{
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 80;

  server_name stage.domain.com;

  ...
}

#Rental cars site ssl enforced
server
{
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name hyrbil.domain.com;

  ...
}

#ios redirect to enforce https
server
{
  listen 80;

  server_name ios.domain.com;

  return 301 https://ios.domain.com$request_uri;
}

#android redirect to enforce https
server
{
  listen 80;

  server_name android.domain.com;

  return 301 https://android.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Bonus question:
Is it possible to match all ssl traffic and do a redirect unless it matches a specific domain, for example make https://xxx.domain.com pass a 301 to https://www.domain.com even tho i don't have a certificate for xxx.domain.com without showing "This page is unsecure, are you sure that you want to proceeed"?

Comment: nginx have always choose a server that will answer to request. If it cannot match `server_name` it will choose _default_ (usually first one) server block for `port`.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have one virtualhost listening on 443, all traffic reaches your IP address will be served by that virtualhost.

Create an SSL virtualhost for domain.com and put a simple redirect in it.

Or create a "catch all/default" SSL virtualhost, and check the HOST header and redirect regarding that, like:

`if ($host !~* ^www\.doman\.com$) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
        }`

But it will show SSL certificate error on all FQDNs not included in your certificate!